# Issues with the linux read syscall

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I just started learning x86 assembly so im sorry if this question is too stupid. So heres my code that checks if a number read from stdin is even or not:

```
section .data
    even db "even",10   ;even number
    odd db "odd",10     ;odd number
section .bss
    num resb 1
section .text
    global _start

_start:
    
    mov rax, 0  ;read
    mov rdi, 0  ;stdin
    mov rsi, num    ;where to store
    mov rdx, 1  ;count
    syscall
    

    mov eax,num ;num in eax. div requires dividend in eax
    xor edx, edx    ;clear edx
    mov ebx, 2  ;mov 2 in ebx
    div ebx     ;divide
    cmp edx, 0x00   ;remaider goes in edx
    je evenl    ;jump if equals
    

    mov rax, 1  ;write
    mov rdi, 1  ;stdout
    mov rsi, odd    ;message
    mov rdx, 4  ;count
    syscall 

    mov rax, 60 ;exit
    mov rdi, 0  ;code 0
    syscall


evenl:
    mov rax, 1  ;write
    mov rdi , 1 ;stdout
    mov rsi , even  ;message
    mov rdx, 5  ;count
    syscall

    mov rax, 60 ;exit
    mov rdi, 0  ;code 0
    syscall
```

No matter what, it always says the number is even. even if there is no input. However, if i hardcode the value in eax at line 18, it works perfectly fine. what am i doing wrong? How may i fix this?

compiled with `nasm -felf64`

Comment: `mov eax, num` loads the address of `num` into `eax`.  Try `movzbl eax, [num]` and then `sub eax, '0'` to turn the digit into a number.  Note further that assembly is assembled, not compiled.

Comment: You are loading the address not the value. Also,you are loading 4 bytes not 1 but that doesn't change even or odd so you are lucky. Instead of `mov eax,num` use `movzx eax, byte [num]`.

Comment: @Jester i did that and now i wont even wait for stdin. it just directly prints even now

Comment: That should in no way change the wait as it's after that. You likely changed something else.

Comment: @fuz: `movzbl` is the AT&T mnemonic for `movzx reg, byte`.  I was curious if NASM would accept `movzbl`; it doesn't.

Comment: Using `div` with a constant 2 is a very inefficient way to test for even.  Use `test byte [num], 1` to check the low bit of the ASCII digit, which will be the same as the low bit of the integer it represents.  (Because `'0'` is an even number.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry, I gave the wrong mnemonic.

Comment: In your revised code ([pastebin](https://pastebin.com/mCrgcBQQ)) `mov rax, num ;read` should be `mov rax, 0 ;read` . The output is always even because there is never any input. This comment is now in response to a deleted comment.

Comment: Also sys_read includes the newline character in the buffer, so you need to make your buffer 2 bytes long. So even with the fixed code you'll get even when you don't enter anything is because there's still a newline character being written and you're reading it and the newline character is character code 12 which is even.

Comment: @Faissaloo: That part seems okay to me.  `read` is being given a count of 1, so the newline will simply remain unread (and maybe confuse the shell, but that's a separate issue), and the 1-byte buffer will contain the 1 character that came before the newline.